# How to close the ADO connection if the database connection fails while inside a transaction

Tags: c++, transactions, database-connection, ado, rollback

I am using ADO via C++, and let's suppose that I have begun a transaction via ADO when the connection drops out.

I wish to abandon my database changes and close my ADO database connection object, in order to return to another code module which can display an error message (without leaving this module in a dodgy state).

The problem is:

1) I cannot close the database connection because the error adErrInTransaction (0x800a0cae) is thrown (connection object cannot be explicitly closed while in a transaction)

2) I cannot rollback the transaction because the error 0x8000ffff is thrown (catastrophic failure, .... connection failure)

This appears to be a catch 22 situation.  Had it been that the transaction was not started then calling Close on the ADO connection succeeds, but unfortunately with the transaction open I appear to be stuck!

Is the only solution to record the fact that it's failed within a transaction, so that when the database connection is restored, I can complete the rollback before attempting anything else?

This was tested with SQLServer 2008 if it's relevant, though I don't really want a SQLServer-specific solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, didnt do this in a long time but:

1) you have to start your transaction with `db.BeginTransaction();` and not with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198024/en-us )

2) simply kill the transaction when you notice your connection went down
via:

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("ado...");
SqlTransaction transaction;

db.Open();
transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
//..........
// stuff here 
//..........
if ( connGone ) {
transaction.rollback();
db.close(); }
```

Comment: Thanks @Najzero, I'm interested to know that this works.  Unfortunately due to the fact that the code has to support Oracle as well as SQLServer, the call is actually using an ADODB::_ConnectionPtr, calling the BeginTrans method which returns a transaction-level as far as I'm aware.  I'm not aware that there is such a thing as an ADODB::TransactionPtr, so maybe this is not possible through ADO.  Thanks for the tip though, and I'll have a look at your link.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem of Unknown Exception.  I had called BeginTransaction.  Even though it never hit the DB the connection needed the rollBack called before I could close the DB connection.

Comment: In JScript, `with (db) { some ops }` throws the connection fail exception. Without `with`, the exception is not thrown.